# Updating website's style with SASS and uploading it to server

Tags: css, sass

I made changes to my website styles using the specific SASS file for the specific page that I updated. Now, in order to make this changes to my published website (until now, everything was done locally), should I upload just the modified SASS file? Or should I upload the main SASS and CSS files where everything is being compiled locally?

Comment: The sass website should describe how to use sass.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question: the solution is to upload the newly modified SASS file, together with the main SASS file and the CSS file and it will work.

Comment: Sass files don't play any role in the website.You can only upload css files that you link to your page.